# Traversing a List of Hashmaps in drools

Tags: java, drools

In Drools drl file how do we access HashMaps in a List by traversing the list.

Say Account is a class having a `List<HashMap<String,String>> hmList`.

How do I traverse through each of the `HashMap` to check for a condition?

Comment: Which language are you using in "then" part of the rule ? I mean dialect

Comment: I want to traverse in the "when" part, for the "then" part I'm using Java.

Comment: check the following link http://javacodeimpl.blogspot.com/2013/11/drools-drl-hashmapmap-collection.html

Comment: fwiw - That example is a few lines longer than it needs to be. They could have written `entry : Entry(value == "Thane") from $cityPlaces.entrySet()` ... anything with a 'get' method can be evaluated like that. Although, it's worth pointing out that such an example might also have been improved by inserting each `Place` as a separate fact. i.e. Just because it's a `Map` in Java code doesn't mean it needs to be a `Map` in working memory.

Comment: @Steve  Almost - `Entry( value contains "Thane" )`

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida That rule is strange. As Steve has pointed out, it might have ended with the Entry() pattern. Or it might have ended with String( toString == "Thane" ). Or with eval(value == "Thane") - no need to avoid eval() and "escape" into the horribly contrived Boolean()